# Merge all factors where the cummulative sum of a column is less than 0.05

Tags: r, charts, merge

I have a dataset with densities for different marine zooplankton organisms.
I want to present this as either a barplot or pie chart, but there are too many organisms and a lot of labels end up on top of each other.

I'd like to merge all organisms whose cummulative sum for the column "fraction" is less than 5% into a new factor "other".

Here is a dput() of the data frame I'm working with:

```
structure(list(species = structure(c(1L, 4L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 11L, 
15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 21L, 23L, 26L, 28L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 39L, 
40L, 41L, 43L), .Names = c("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""), .Label = c("Beroe     cucumis", 
"Beroe cucumis larvae", "Boroecia borealis", "Bradyidus similis", 
"C. hyperboreus AF", "C. hyperboreus CIV", "Calanus egg", "Calanus nauplii", 
"Calanus spp.", "Chaetognatha spp.", "Cirripedia nauplii", "Conchoecia     borealis", 
"Cyclopoida", "Echinodermata larvae", "Eukrohnia hamata", "Euphausiacea furcilia", 
"Euphausiacea nauplii", "Fish larvae", "Fritillaria borealis", 
"Hymenodora glacialis", "Idyrea furcata ", "Krill nauplii", "Medusa", 
"Mertensia ovum", "Metridia longa", "Microcalanus spp.", "Microsetella norvegica", 
"Oithona similis", "Oithona spp.", "Paraeuchaeta barbata AF", 
"Paraeuchaeta barbata CII", "Paraeuchaeta barbata CV", "Paraeuchaeta glacialis", 
"Paraeuchaeta spp.", "Parasagitta elegans", "Polychaeta larvae", 
"Pseudocalanus spp.", "Scyphozoa larvae", "Thysanoessa inermis", 
"Thysanoessa longicaudata", "Thysanoessa raschii", "Triconia borealis", 
"Zoea larvae"), class = "factor"), density = c(4, 3, 205, 1431, 
197, 1786, 1, 11, 50, 1, 36, 4, 1, 34, 26, 13, 83, 30, 8, 1, 
0, 26), location = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Names = c("tmp_location", 
"tmp_location", "tmp_location", "tmp_location", "tmp_location", 
"tmp_location", "tmp_location", "tmp_location", "tmp_location", 
"tmp_location", "tmp_location", "tmp_location", "tmp_location", 
"tmp_location", "tmp_location", "tmp_location", "tmp_location", 
"tmp_location", "tmp_location", "tmp_location", "tmp_location", 
"tmp_location"), .Label = c("Hinlopen", "ICE", "KB3", "Karl Kronedjupet"
), class = "factor"), fraction = c(0.00101240192356365, 0.000759301442672741, 
0.0518855985826373, 0.362186788154898, 0.04986079473551, 0.452037458871172, 
0.000253100480890914, 0.00278410528980005, 0.0126550240445457, 
0.000253100480890914, 0.00911161731207289, 0.00101240192356365, 
0.000253100480890914, 0.00860541635029107, 0.00658061250316376, 
0.00329030625158188, 0.0210073399139458, 0.00759301442672741, 
0.00202480384712731, 0.000253100480890914, 0, 0.00658061250316376
)), .Names = c("species", "density", "location", "fraction"), row.names = c(87L, 
90L, 93L, 94L, 95L, 97L, 101L, 102L, 103L, 104L, 105L, 107L, 
109L, 112L, 114L, 121L, 122L, 123L, 125L, 126L, 127L, 129L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could represent this using a waffle chart.

```
#Install waffle package from github
library(devtools) #make sure you have this installed
devtools::install_github("hrbrmstr/waffle")

library(waffle)

# separate rows with fractions lower than 5%
others <- df[df$fraction <.05,]
df1 <- df[df$fraction >=.05,]

# get summed values of others
others.fraction <- sum(others$fraction)
others.density <- sum(others$density)

#bind others back into df1
df2 <- rbind(df1, data.frame(species="other", density = others.density, location = "KB3", fraction = others.fraction))

# make a named vector (waffle likes this as the input) - I'm plotting densities here

densities <- df2$density
names(densities) <- df2$species
densities <- rev(sort(densities))


#plot - I'm dividing by 10 so the chart isn't too big
# I also added a title

waffle(densities/10, rows=10) + ggtitle("Something about Zooplankton")
```

This gives this plot:

[image]

You can modify this chart in the same way as ggplot graphs - waffle is a convenience wrapper for ggplot functions.

ps. don't use pie charts !

Comment: Nice, I didn't know about waffle charts.
Your way of picking out the lower 5% works well enough, but not exactly like I was thinking.
If possible I'd like to merge all groups whose _cummulative_ sum for "fraction" =< 5%.